# Wrapped types autoboxing vs "new" CODE TEST

Tags: java, wrapper, primitive-types, autoboxing

I know from theory that creating a new wrapped number type should be made using autoboxing or factory methods, instead of using `new` because of the caching feature.
So i made a little test program just to experience but the results are unexpeted.
Here is the code:

```
package javaTest;

public class TestWrapper {
    public static final int NUM_TESTS = 50000000;
    public static final int SAMPLE_NUMBER = 100;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        long time = 0;

        System.out.println("Testing with " + NUM_TESTS + " iterations:");

        System.out.println("\nTesting Double");
        TestType[] types = TestType.values();
        for(int i=0; i<types.length; i++) {
            time = 0;
            for(int j=0; j<SAMPLE_NUMBER; j++) {
                time += testDouble(types[i]);
            }
            System.out.println( "\t" + types[i].toString("Double") + " mean execution time: " + (((double)time)/SAMPLE_NUMBER) + "ms");
        }

        System.out.println("\nTesting Integer");
        for(int i=0; i<types.length; i++) {
            time = 0;
            for(int j=0; j<SAMPLE_NUMBER; j++) {
                time += testInteger(types[i]);
                //System.out.println(j);
            }
            System.out.println("\t" + types[i].toString("Integer") + " mean execution time: " + (((double)time)/SAMPLE_NUMBER) + "ms");
        }
    }

    public static long testInteger(TestType type) {
        Integer test;
        long startTime=0;
        long endTime=0;

        switch (type) {
        case NEW:
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TESTS; i++) {
                test = new Integer(0);
            }
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            break;

        case VALUEOF:
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TESTS; i++) {
                test = Integer.valueOf(0);
            }
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            break;

        case AUTOBOXING:
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TESTS; i++) {
                test = 0;
            }
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            break;
        }
        return (endTime - startTime);
    }

    public static long testDouble(TestType type) {
        Double test;
        long startTime=0;
        long endTime=0;

        switch (type) {
        case NEW:
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TESTS; i++) {
                test = new Double(0);
            }
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            break;

        case VALUEOF:
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TESTS; i++) {
                test = Double.valueOf(0);
            }
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            break;

        case AUTOBOXING:
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TESTS; i++) {
                test = .0;
            }
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            break;
        }
        return (endTime - startTime);
    }

    private enum TestType {
        NEW, VALUEOF, AUTOBOXING;

        public String toString(String type) {
            String ret = new String();
            switch(this) {
                case NEW:
                    ret = "new " + type + "(0)";
                    break;
                case VALUEOF:
                    ret = type + ".valueOf(0)";
                    break;
                case AUTOBOXING:
                    ret = type + " a = 0";
                    break;
            }
            return ret;
        }
    }

}
```

And the output is:
(Compiled and ran with jdk1.6.0_23)

> Testing with 50000000 iterations:
>
> Testing Double
>   new Double(0) mean execution time: 20.18ms
>   Double.valueOf(0) mean execution time: 210.18ms
>  
>   Double a = .0 mean execution time: 207.73ms
>
> Testing Integer
>  
>   new Integer(0) mean execution time: 20.08ms
>   Integer.valueOf(0) mean execution time: 160.64ms
>   Integer a = .0 mean execution time: 160.77ms

As I said, i was expecting the first test to be the slowest, but the output says the opposite!
Why is this happening?

UPDATE

(Compiled and ran with jdk1.7.0_79)

> Testing with 50000000 iterations:
>
> Testing Double
>     new Double(0) mean execution time: 1.5ms
>     Double.valueOf(0) mean execution time: 213.86ms
>      Double a = 0
>   mean execution time: 214.29ms
>
> Testing Integer
>    new Integer(0) mean execution time: 1.3ms
>     Integer.valueOf(0) mean execution time: 141.55ms
>     Integer a = 0
>   mean execution time: 141.38ms

(Compiled and ran with jdk1.8.0_121)

> Testing with 50000000 iterations:
>
> Testing Double
>     new Double(0) mean execution time: 0.1ms
>     Double.valueOf(0) mean execution time: 0.0ms
>     Double a = 0 mean
>   execution time: 0.0ms
>
> Testing Integer
>    new Integer(0) mean execution time: 0.1ms
>     Integer.valueOf(0) mean execution time: 0.0ms
>    Integer a = 0 mean
>   execution time: 0.0ms

The same test with 100000000 iterations give this output on jdk1.8:

(Compiled and ran with jdk1.8.0_121)

> Testing with 100000000 iterations:
>
> Testing Double
>     new Double(0) mean execution time: 54.02ms
>     Double.valueOf(0) mean execution time: 62.99ms
>   Double a = 0 mean
>   execution time: 62.93ms
>
> Testing Integer
>    new Integer(0) mean execution time: 53.44ms
>     Integer.valueOf(0) mean execution time: 63.01ms
>      Integer a = 0
>   mean execution time: 62.93ms

Comment: Are you sure of these results? I ran the code in my machine and I got different results, also since you keep using the same number (0) only the first round should take more time for valueOf , after that it will be cached

Comment: Interesting test but you should improve it to warm up the VM (use a benchmark framework) and add a test with more random values.

Comment: To get useful results you could run your tests in a infinite loop to see how the VM optimizes the code over time. After times do not change anymore you are ready to compare how they would perform i a long running application.

Comment: I agree with the comments above that you should use some benchmark framework, like [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/). By the way, don't you think that testing `new Double` and `Double.valueOf` is pointless cause second method just calls the first (Look at the source code of `Double` class)?

Comment: I run it on my machine and my output is totally different Testing with 50000000 iterations:

Testing Double
 new Double(0) mean execution time: 0.11ms
 Double.valueOf(0) mean execution time: 0.0ms
 Double a = 0 mean execution time: 0.0ms

Testing Integer
 new Integer(0) mean execution time: 0.09ms
 Integer.valueOf(0) mean execution time: 0.0ms
 Integer a = 0 mean execution time: 0.0ms .

Comment: @wbars: This is what I  was thinking too... But i made this because i always read about autoboxing and `.valueOf()` being a better choice for performance purposes. Anyway i'll go deeper soon